# How does Ignite work with Spark from the Integration view

Tags: ignite

There is an `IngiteRDD` that can reflect changes to the underlying cache which is very nice in some cases to overcome the shortcoming of immutability of Spark' RDD.

There is an `IgniteRDD.sql` method that runs `ANSI sql (not spark sql)`, this method returns a DataFrame that is the concept of spark sql. When I get this DataFrame object, can i use it as a normal DataFrame that I don't need to think that it is from Ignite world? That is, I can register temp table, and then do distributed join with other DataFrame. When sql like distribued join, is executed, does Ignite use Spark SQL Engine or the Ignite Engine to run the sql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dataframe` API after you executed a query, but in this case it will not be distributed. I.e. it will work with the local result set already fetched to the driver.

Full `Dataframe` support in Ignite will be available next year.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin for the explanation.If the data is fetched to the driver side, then I would to think that the data should be smaller enough...which makes `IgniteRDD.sql` only suitable for small data set?

Comment: The whole data set is not transferred to the driver, only result set. The query itself is executed on a scalable distributed cache which can store gigabytes of data.